# Can't read from socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have set up an pi zero running a simple python server script on my local network to respond to certain commands. I am trying to send those commands from an android java app. But when I try to read the reply from the command I have sent it seems like it skipes the line. Because "D/Sending data: Data has been send" is the last thing printed to the log.

This is the nested runnable class I am using to sent a command and then print the reply from the server:

```
private class SendData implements Runnable
    {
        private byte[] dataToSend;
        private Socket socket;
        private OutputStream outputStream;

        private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        public SendData(Socket socket, byte[] dataToSend)
        {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.dataToSend = dataToSend;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(dataToSend);
                Log.d("Sending data", "Data has been send");
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                Log.d("Received", bufferedReader.readLine());

            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e("IOException Sending data", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I try to read from the bufferedreader the applications just quits. While the server did sent a reply.

The thread gets started from from this method where "data" is a string.

```
if (socket != null)
        {
            Thread sendThread = new Thread(new SendData(socket, data.getBytes()));
            Log.d("SocketClient send", "Starting send thread");
            sendThread.start();
            try
            {
                sendThread.join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Log.d("SocketClient constructor", "Could not join");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("SocketClient send", "Socket is null");
        }
```

Python script running on the pi:

```
import socket
import sys
from datetime import datetime

host = "192.168.4.1"
port = 12345

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind((host, port))

sock.listen(1)

def data_client(conn, ipStr):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        reply = handle_command(data)
        print "Command: %s" % data
        if not data or data == "con_close":
            print "Connection %s closed" % ipStr
            break
        conn.send(reply)
        print "Send: %s" % reply
    conn.close()

def handle_command(cmd):
    if (cmd == "con_close"):
        return cmd
    elif (cmd == "get_time"):
        return str(datetime.now())
    else:
        return "err_invalid_command"

while True:
    print "listening:"
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print "Got connection from %s" % addr[0]
    data_client(conn, addr[0])
```

Comment: Just quits, or writes a stacktrace? Any reason you're using raw sockets instead of an HTTP request on the pi?

Comment: @cricket_007 No particular reason. I am not really sure what happends it almost seems like it skips the "bufferedReader.readLine()" because the last thing that gets printed is "D/Sending data: Data has been send". Not a logged exception. The app doesn't cras.

Comment: Are you sure you're giving the correct IP address for the socket? Are there logs on the pi of any data?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes I am sure these are the logs from the pi: 
"Got connection from 192.168.4.8
Command: get_time
Send: 2018-04-15 13:12:18.003816"

Comment: And can you add the pi code that is supposed to send data back?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes of course, I added it to my post. I tried connecting to the pi with an app that can test tcp connections. I did got a valid response when I send a command that way.

Comment: `read the reply from the command I have sent it seems like it skipes the line`. Well put a log statement after that line and if you see that log statement and not the one of readLine() then it would have been skipped. Bugt i do not be!ieve that. I think it sticks in readLine().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the receiver tries to read a line then the sender should have send one.

The receiver tries to read a line with `readLine()` but readLine() never returns as it waits for a newline char that has not been sent.